# Python: len() of unknown numpy array column length

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently trying to learn Python and Numpy. The task is to determine the length of individual columns of an imported CSV file.

So far I have:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt("assignment5_data.csv", delimiter = ',')
print (data.shape[:])
```

Which returns:

```
(62, 2)
```

Is there a way to iterate through each column to count [not is.nan]?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and you are trying to get the length of non-nan values in each column, use:

```
np.sum(~np.isnan(data),axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks, Sacul. You've been a great help.